# Find a starting index of given word from string in looped LinkedList

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I am trying to generate a program in java, which takes string input and second input as a word, which I am trying to find starting index of that word from the string given. If word is occurring more than once it should give all the starting indexes.

**Input string:**

```
ped come wrapped to wrap
```

**Input Word(it's starting index needs to be find):**

wrapped

**Desire Output:**

9 20

I have produced a program which finds starting index of given word. However, I am struggling to add one more logic like, if you see my input string's (last_word + first_word) = `wrapped` (a word i am looking for ) so I need get starting index of last word too in output.

This is what I have generated so far.

```
public class Practice {

    public static void findWordIndex(String text, String word) {

        for (int i = text.length(); (i = text.lastIndexOf(word, i - 1)) != -1; ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Practice p = new Practice();
        p.findWordIndex("ped come wrapped the wrap", "wrapped");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you considering warp and warped as a same word ?

Comment: No but last word "wrap" and first word "ped" should also matched so it is consider as a wrapped@seal

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start so far.

This should solve your problem:

```
public static String findWordIndex(String text, String word) {
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){ //Start looping through the text

        if(text.charAt(i) == word.charAt(0)){ //If the first letter matches
            startIndex = i;
            for(int j = 1; j < word.length(); j++){ //Check the rest of the word to see if remaining characters match

                if(word.charAt(j) != text.charAt(j+i)){ //If one of the characters suddenly doesn't match, reset the process
                    startIndex = -1;
                    break;
                } else if(j == word.length()-1){ //We're at the end of the word and all of the characters have matched so far
                    endIndex = i+j;
                    return "Start: " + startIndex + ", End: " + endIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null; //if all else fails, return null
}
```

I hope this helps.  If it doesn't, let me know!  Also, when you do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Practice p = new Practice();
    p.findWordIndex("ped come wrapped the wrap", "wrapped");
}
```

You should not have to create an instance of the class that you're currently working in.  You should just be able to call findWordIndex directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    findWordIndex("ped come wrapped the wrap", "wrapped");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I tried your program but I am not getting any output. Can  you justify how it works?
You are going to return something but the method is void type and it is not return any type so how can we get output?

Comment: Yeah, I think I know why it's not getting any input.  If you look at your function, you had: ..........

public static void findWordIndex(String text, String word){..........

When you put "void" as your return type, that meant it returns nothing.  If you want to see the start and end indices, you can change void to String and where the return statement is, you can put 'return "Start: " + startIndex + ", End: " + endIndex;' without the single quotes around that statement.

Comment: Then later where you call the function, you can store it in a variable like so:  .......... var output = findWordIndex("ped come wrapped the wrap", "wrapped"); ......... and then if you want to see that output, put System.out.println(output); on the next line.

Comment: I think you are not getting my question please look at once again.

Comment: OP has already solved to get starting index of occurring word. however he is not getting the way to write program if LastWord + FirstWord of string = "Word needs to be searched" then it should also count as one more occurrence of particular word and should written index of it. In OP's case 9 and 20 should be output. @Bob

Comment: @ChintanPanchal Ah yes, I just noticed I forgot some ending braces for my if statements.  I updated my answer with the correct code.  Try that out.

Comment: @ShyamBhimani Oh, I did not understand that from the question.  Sorry.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm not quite sure how to answer it other than how I've done above.

Comment: From your code I am getting output  Start: 9, End: 15 but output will be Start: 9, 20. Only the first index of the word

Answer (score 0):

At the expense of whitespaces i have found a way to get the indexes of your string according to your problem, i didn't use `IndexOf()` in this solution, what i did is that i have used two `Arraylist`s one for words (with whitespaces ommited) and the other is for the length of each string, i used iterations to get the indexes of those strings, and checked if the combination of two words `equal`s the disired `word` my output after ommitting whitespaces is **[7, 16]** .Here is my code :

```
public class play1  {

    public void methodd(String text , String word){

        List<String> textArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+")));

        ArrayList <Integer> listOfIndexes = new ArrayList();

        List<Integer> textlength = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < textArray.size(); i++) {
            textlength.add(textArray.get(i).length());
        }
        for (int i=0;i< textArray.size();i++) {
            if (textArray.get(i).equals(word)) {
                int stringLength=0;
                for (int k = 0; k <i; k++) {
                     stringLength= stringLength+textlength.get(k);
                }  
                listOfIndexes.add(stringLength+1);
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < textArray.size(); j++) {
                if ((textArray.get(i)+textArray.get(j)).equals(word) ) {
                    int stringLength=0;
                    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
                         stringLength= stringLength+textlength.get(z);
                    }  
                    listOfIndexes.add(stringLength+1);

                  break;         
                }
            }
            System.out.println(listOfIndexes);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "ped come wrapped to wrap";
    String word="wrapped";
    play1 s = new play1();
    s.methodd(text,word);
    //prints [7,16] counting only letters and ommitting whitespaces




    }

}
```

Comment: what would be the output in test case: `ped come wrapped to wrap` and word is `wrapped` ?

Comment: The output would be [9], since the word wrapped is only mentioned once in the text.

Comment: In that case your answer is not addressing OP's issue. as `wrap+ped` = `wrapped` means lastWord + firstWord = searching word too so this suppose to give output [9] and [20].

Comment: @ShyamBhimani ok solved the problem at the expense of ommiting white spaces so the desired output changes to [7,16], it adresses the problem OP had originaly, hope this helps :)